# Gridview button not firing its method

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I populate a gridview called grdOrder by using a method which uses a series of other classes and stored procedures (it's so ugly that even I don't understand because it's given by our professor and he's confused us on whole new level)

I then want to delete an item from the database based on value (OrderId) which is in the second rows in the GridView once it is populated.

In the row editor of Gridview I created a button and when I double click the gridview in design view it creates the follow

```
protected void grdOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So that is what I think should be firing when I hit the button remove on the Gridview. So I put a break underneath that method and it does not fire when I do that on the form in the browser. So it's not working basically.

If you want to see more of what's going on here is the full codes

http://pastebin.com/iSvyJCPQ - Aspx page
http://pastebin.com/LVRvaCnu - Code Behind (C#)

Comment: You need RowCommand event not selectedindexchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Gridview.RowCommand event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: Alright so I did that however it still isn't firing. Here is the updated code http://pastebin.com/tUdk5PL7 . This is how the aspx gridview looks like <asp:GridView ID="grdOrder" runat="server" Height="222px" Width="640px" >     
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField Text="Remove" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Remove" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: @Jagga, add OnRowCommand="grdOrder_RowCommand" to your GridView tag, please refer to MSDN articles and learn how to bind events.

Comment: Ah that is what it was, it has fixed it now. It fires when i debug it. Thanks folks! Now I just need to get the method to work :)  @Jhigs